# How to use LINQ to generate new type of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `List<T>` of objects with different types (i.e., `List<Apple>` and `List<Tiger>`).  Now I want to combine properties from the 2 objects to generate a new (anonymous) type of objects.

How do I achieve with LINQ?

Comment: what are the properties there in the Apple and Triger

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So do you just want to combine the first element of the apple list with the first element of the tiger list?

If so, and if you're using .NET 4, you can use [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
var results = apples.Zip(tigers, (apple, tiger) => 
                   new { apple.Colour, tiger.StripeCount });
```

If you're not using .NET 4, you could use our implementation of `Zip` in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com).

If you wanted to match apples with tigers in some other way, you probably want to use a join:

```
var results = from apple in apples
              join tiger in tigers on apple.Name equals tiger.Name
              select new { apple.Color, tiger.StripeCount };
```

Comment: Actually, I'm finding cross joining feature. But still thanks your help.

Comment: @Ricky: If you're *able* to use a join clause rather than a cross join, it will be more efficient.